# Data frame transformation - create a ranked data frame based on score values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It was a bit hard write a more explanatory problem title but here is a more detailed explanation.

I have a quadratic dataframe that looks like the below. Index names = column names and for each image there is a similarity score calculated. For each image name, I need to extract the top n most similar images (ranked by the scores) and store them in a data frame that does not take so much space.

```
               name_A.jpg     name_B.jpg     name_C.jpg     name_D.jpg   ...

name_A.jpg     1.000000       0.725098       0.291748       0.444336
name_B.jpg     0.725098       1.000000       0.255371       0.482178
name_C.jpg     0.291748       0.255371       1.000000       0.382812
name_D.jpg     0.444336       0.482178       0.382812       1.000000
name_E.jpg     0.197998       0.276611       0.183594       0.242065
name_F.jpg     0.309570       0.292236       0.327148       0.387695
name_G.jpg     0.302490       0.280273       0.339844       0.377197
name_H.jpg     0.261475       0.278076       0.258301       0.323975
name_J.jpg     0.243164       0.261963       0.304932       0.314453
name_K.jpg     0.269043       0.254639       0.247681       0.259766
name_L.jpg     0.251465       0.238892       0.227539       0.233887
name_M.jpg     0.287354       0.299805       0.216553       0.259766
name_N.jpg     0.413818       0.460938       0.239136       0.358398
name_O.jpg     0.394043       0.489258       0.293701       0.526855
name_P.jpg     0.262451       0.235229       0.224487       0.210083
name_Q.jpg     0.124634       0.137695       0.095032       0.142944
name_R.jpg     0.173218       0.187134       0.203491       0.194092
...
```

So the desired output is something like this:

```
               0              1              2              3              ....          n
name_A.jpg     name_B.jpg     name_D.jpg     name_N.jpg     name_O.jpg     
name_B.jpg
name_C.jpg
name_D.jpg
...
```

So if I look at `name_A.jpg` on a website, the recommended products are `name_b.jpg, name_D.jpg, name_N.jpg, name_O.jpg` .... In my case I've got around 300,000 images and I want to display the top n = 50 most similar images, hence the desired output data frame will have dimensions 300,000 x 50.

Of course I could just subset each column, use `sort()` in descending order and cap the top 50 rows. This requires however a for loop doing the same thing 300 000 times. Is there some other faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert values of columns and `DataFrame` to numpy array and get positions of descending order values by convert array to nagetive values, then filter ouput first top1 value (because always `1`) and get top `N` columns values to new `DataFrame`:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()

N = 3
df = pd.DataFrame(cols[np.argsort(-arr)[:, 1:N+1]], index=df.index)
print (df.head(4))
                     0           1           2
name_A.jpg  name_B.jpg  name_D.jpg  name_C.jpg
name_B.jpg  name_A.jpg  name_D.jpg  name_C.jpg
name_C.jpg  name_D.jpg  name_A.jpg  name_B.jpg
name_D.jpg  name_B.jpg  name_A.jpg  name_C.jpg
```